# Custom MessageBodyWriter for Long datatype not being called

Tags: java, rest, cxf

I have a return type for a REST service, that contains a Long field. When this field is NULL, the returned XML skips that field. I want the field to be present in the output, as an empty element.

For eg: if the POJO definition is as follows:

```
class Employee
{
  String name;
  Integer rating;
}
```

The returned XML is

```
<root><employee><name>John</name></employee></root>
```

whereas I want it to be:

```
<root><employee><name>John</name><rating></rating></employee></root>
```

In order to do this, I wrote a custom messagebodywriter as per instructions in http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-MessageBodyProviders

```
@Produces("text/plain")
public class NullableLongWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Long> {

    public long getSize(Long l, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mt) {
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mt) {
        return long.class.isAssignableFrom(type) || Long.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public void writeTo(Long l, Class<?> clazz, Type type, Annotation[] a,
                        MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers, OutputStream os)
            throws IOException
    {
        if (l == null)
            os.write("".toString().getBytes());
        else
            os.write(l.toString().getBytes());

    }
}
```

But it is not being called for the Long type. It is only being called for the Employee class.

How do I get the custom messagebodywriter to be invoked for all types?

Answer (score 0):

Your NullableLongWriter would be used if your controller would return a Long value. Its not used to serialize the long field of your Employee class.

But you can influence XML-serialization of your Pojo using JAXB annotations:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Employee
{
     String name;
     @XmlElement(nillable=true)
     Integer rating;
}
```

Your example would be serialized to

```
<employee>
    <name>John</name>
    <rating xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</employee>
```

which is rather ugly. Why won't you accept that the rating element is not in the XML?

Comment: Thanks! I am using beautifulsoup on the client side to parse the xml, and wanted the empty element in it. Otherwise beautifulsoup throws an exception.

Comment: SHould I create a messagebodywriter for my Pojo and implement it to write the empty element instead?

Comment: CXF should be able to serialize to XML out of the box.